# I need to prevent going back to a page that you uses NavigationExtras state data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4, angular7-router

I'm using Angular 7 Router navigationExtras state to send data (json) to a page, and I want to prevent going back to this page when I have navigated forward.

I tried using conditions in "recieverDataPage" so when I dont have data it goes back to the previous page, but it looks bad, I dont think it can be considered as good practices.

I'm sharing my code that I'm using in "dataPage" and "recieverDataPage":

DataPage passing data code:

```
openTicketDetail(ticket: any) { 
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      state: {
        ticket: ticket
      }
   };
this.router.navigate(['/menu/ticket-detail'], navigationExtras);
}
```

recieverDataPage getting data code:

```
export class TicketDetailPage implements OnInit {
  ticket:any;
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
        this.ticket = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.ticket;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

My navigation history goes like this:
dataPage -> recieverDataPage -> anotherPage

It works fine when I go from dataPage to recieverDataPage but when I go back from anotherPage to recieverDataPage my data that should be there is undefined and I want to prevent that, maybe skiping the navigationBack to this page.

Comment: If you have some code that can detect this then consider [using a Route Guard](https://www.joshmorony.com/prevent-access-to-pages-in-ionic-with-angular-route-guards/) which can intercept and redirect if the page doesn't meet the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an onDismiss function inside the receiverDataPage with the values you already have inside the page. This function runs when the anotherPage dismisses, which in this case would be the navigate back.
If it doesn’t work with the router, you can try NavController of ionic. If that doesn’t work you can achieve it with a modal which you don’t really need to run any onDismiss since the modal will open inside the current page and you won’t lose any data on receiverDataPage.

I can explain better once i get hold on to my pc with some coding to it :D